# How to return a website and automatically redirect to another side which takes long to load

Tags: python, flask

I ask the user to input some data, after that I redirect him to a 'result' website which takes several seconds to load.

I don't like this, because there is no user feedback telling him, that the server has not crashed and that his result is coming. So I was thinking about showing the user a 'loading' website stating 'please wait' and then automatically redirect him to the 'result' page. The user would see the "please-wait"-website the whole time the other one is loading, as Flask does not serve the site before it is finished with the calculations.

**[Attempt to clarify]**
One of the pages takes so long, because it waits for a [file upload](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/). The other side takes  so long because its functions wait for data from a third party api.

How would I do that in Flask?

Comment: after click you can show the message "loading" because your page is going to close anyway.. right? or is in a new tab??

Comment: Does the page take too long to load because of its page elements or because of some process with Flask? If its the latter, I think Celery is the right tool for this. Otherwise, maybe Javascript can do the job.

Comment: @SamratManSingh I added some hopeful useful clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask's documentation for file uploads includes a section on [implementing progress bars for file uploads](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/#upload-progress-bars). Choose one of the many client-side solutions to display the progress of the upload and then redirect once the upload is complete.

For the long-running server side process you have several options:

- Pre-fetch (and *cache*) the data from the slow-to-respond API.
- Hijack your link's action with JavaScript and make an ajax request for the data - update the DOM with a status message to let the user know that everything is still working.
- Have a three step process.  Page #1 has a link to the "Please wait ... " page (Page #2).  Page #2 has a meta refresh tag pointing at Page #3 (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/path/to/page3">`)

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest Celery for this, but someone just posted this on the Flask mailing list, and this might be a more simpler solution: [Hello-Redis-Tasks](https://github.com/joeyespo/hello-redis-tasks). If you still want to use Celery though, this is what you should check out: [Custom states in celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states)